# How to Convert a column of "k" (Thousand) & "M" (Million) values into Whole number in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to convert a column with no . of students enrolled in a particular course. but it shows the values in text and format and thousands in "K" & Millions in "M".I want to convert them into whole numbers. Need your help.

Please find attach the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can write a measure that divides the numbers by 1000 or use a calculated column with a substitute:

Column = SUBSTITUTE('Table'[value],"K","")

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
enrolled_int = 
VAR string = [course_students_enrolled]
VAR factor = RIGHT ( string, 1 )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        factor,
        "k", LEFT ( string, LEN ( string ) - 1 ) * 1000,
        "M", LEFT ( string, LEN ( string ) - 1 ) * 1000000,
        VALUE ( string )
    )
```

[image]